# p-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, normed-spaces

For $p>1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we define $\parallel x\parallel_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ where $x_i$ is the $i$th coordinate of $x$. Show that $\lim_{p\to1}\parallel x\parallel_p=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$.

Although this problem seemed simple I couldn't solve it. I thought of finding some proper inequality to apply the squeeze theorem, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It is sufficient to show continuity of the function (of p) near p=1, yes?

Comment: @MarcusAurelius How do I show that the function is continuous at p = 1?

Comment: Yes that suffices....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\ne 0$,
\begin{align*}
\log\|x\|_{p}&=\dfrac{\log\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{p}}{p}\rightarrow\dfrac{\log\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|}{1}=\log\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|x\|_{p}\rightarrow \exp\left(\log\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|.
\end{align*}